# JavaScript Regex: Replace |b| with <b>

Tags: javascript, regex

I've got some funky JSON I'm dealing with, the client is sending it with these odd html tags, |b| and |\br| all over the place. So I want to replace them with  and 
 respectively.

I'm trying to run the following `str.replace` function on the string, but I can't seem to target the pipe characters correctly.

`string.replace(/[|b|]/, '<b>');`

I've also tried `/|b|/`, `/\|b\|/`

Any help is appreciated

Comment: `/\|b\|/` should work, but you need the `g` flag to replace *all* occurrences.

Answer (score 2):

You're declaring a character class with `[|b|]` which means match either `b` or `|`. You need to escape the pipes `\|b\|`since a pipe means "or" in regex.

Comment: This will only replace the first occurrence.

Comment: @RocketHazmat lol, I'll remove that from my answer instead of adding jQuery :)

Answer (score 2):

In regex, `[]` means "one of these characters", so `/[|b|]/` means `|` OR `b`.

You want `/\|b\|/g`.  Without the `g`, it replaces only once.

Comment: Time for me to go home for the day, apparently! ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The correct regex for replacing `|b|` with `<b>` is

```
/\|b\|/
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/vfTG4/